# AND VS OR in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to investigate why my where clause doesn't work correctly.

Query -

```sql
select * from <tablename>
where 
   (column1 <> '0' OR column1 IS NULL) 
OR (column1 NOT LIKE '000%' OR column1 IS NULL)
OR (column1 NOT LIKE 'XXX%' OR column1 IS NULL)
```

This will return all rows

If I change it to -

```sql
select * from <tablename>
where 
   (column1 <> '0' OR column1 IS NULL) 
AND (column1 NOT LIKE '000%' OR column1 IS NULL)
AND (column1 NOT LIKE 'XXX%' OR column1 IS NULL)
```

It will filter correctly.  Maybe I am having an off day but can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Well, they're very different queries, I'd look for the problem there. :P An `OR` is satisfied if either clause is true, an `AND` only when both clauses are true. That plus the actual data in the table ought to be sufficient to explain any difference...

Comment: In your first query, none of those parenthesis need to be there the `WHERE`; all that matters is that *one* of those 6 clauses be true. Considering that for any given  non-`NULL` value either `column1 NOT LIKE '000%'` and `column1 NOT LIKE 'XXX%'` will be true, and you also want rows where the value *is* `NULL` then all your rows are going to be returned.

Comment: Though, in truth, you could shorten the above to `WHERE column1 IS NULL OR (column1 <> '0' AND column1 NOT LIKE '000%' AND column1 NOT LIKE 'XXX%')`

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses.  This is a query that an application is writing with filters in an UI environment.  Have no control on how the query is getting written.  Trying to understand how to use AND vs OR within their app.

Comment: Sounds like you should be asking about *that* application perhaps then; or perhaps talking to their support for assistance, if you aren't the one writing the queries.

Comment: In that process now.  Just trying to figure out why the AND vs OR had different results based exactly how they are writing the queries.  My belief was always like Jeroens but in this instance it doesn't fall into line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the difference just consider following scenario.

You have a row where `column1 = '0'` so it looks at your query. You say `where column1 <> '0'` so this fails. But it goes to next in query which is `where column1 IS NULL` it asks is it `null`? No because it has a value. So two failed. Next `where column1 NOT LIKE '000%'` is it not like `'000%'`? Yes so it returns true and returns you that row. And same happen with other that you try to exclude.

But when using `and` it checks `where column1 <> '0'`? No so fails. Next is it `null`? No failed. So now it fails in all checks because all grouped conditions need to return true.

So in summary `and` needs all to return true. While `or` only one needs to return true.

Just minor improvement on your post `'0'` should be `0` as an `int` not as a `'string'`.

Comment: Great answer.  

To comment on your minor improvement comment - the column1 was a varchar(200).